# OpenGraph publish action display

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am writing here to ask you for some help. I;m trying to publish action "vote" which is connected with built-in object "movie". I can post that action with image, but message is displayed above that image (thumbnail).

I've tried to add some custom properties/field such as "viewers" (Integer), but it didn't succeded. It is not displayed in my timeline.

I want to post thumbnail on the left, and on the right: name of movie and my custom fields or plain text (Side by side). Please help me achieve that effect.

I also noticed that published action is displayed in Activity Feed instead of News Feed or Timeline (profile).

Answer (score 0):

In your app's Open Graph settings, define **Captions** for the **vote** action.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/